# rsnapshot: What's wrong with my crontab?

Tags: rsync, cron, crontab, rsnapshot

I am using Rsnapshot for backups (Linux CentOS 6).

Here is my `/etc/cron.d/rsnapshot`:

```
30 11 * * * root    /usr/bin/rsnapshot nowandthen > /backups/rsnapshot_cron.txt 2>&1
15 11 * * 4 root    /usr/bin/rsnapshot weekly > /backups/rsnapshot_cron.txt 2>&1
00 11 24-31 * 4 root    /usr/bin/rsnapshot monthly > /backups/rsnapshot_cron.txt 2>&1
```

Monthly backup was intended to be executed every last Thursday in any month.

However, monthly backup executed today, Thursday, 2016-Feb-18 at 11:00. Today is not last Thursday in a month.

What's wrong with my crontab?

Comment: what do you see in your logs?

Comment: Your crontab appears to be correct. Do you have the correct date on your computer? What's the output of `date`? Anything relevant in from `grep CRON /var/log/syslog`?

Comment: I can't explain why it ran on 18th, but remember there are several `crontab` files: as well as `/etc` entries there is one for each user, including `root`. Regardless, your script will not do what you want: if the last day of a 31-day month is a Thursday it will run on both 24th and 31st; if the last day of February is a Wednesday it won't run at all.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this site](http://crontab.guru/), your string means “At 11:00 on the 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30 and 31st of every month **and** every Thu.” (my emphasis). If the site is correct this would explain why it ran on 18th.

The example entry in `man 5 crontab` to run on 2nd Saturday is:

```
0 4 8-14 * *    test $(date +\%u) -eq 6 && echo "2nd Saturday"
```

(ie run every day of the second week and check for the week day as part of the command) - this supports the view that the week day is an additional, alternative filter, not a further qualification, though the manual page does not make it clear.

So in your case I would use:

```
00 11 * * 4 root test $(date -d @$((`date +\%s`+604800)) +\%m) -ne $(date +\%m) && /usr/bin/rsnapshot monthly > /backups/rsnapshot_cron.txt 2>&1
```

Check if your `date` supports `-d 'next Thursday'`: if so you can use the rather simpler:

```
00 11 * * 4 root test $(date -d 'next Thu' +\%m) -ne $(date +\%m) && /usr/bin/rsnapshot monthly > /backups/rsnapshot_cron.txt 2>&1
```

This runs every Thursday and checks if the date a week (604800 seconds) from now is in the same month: if not, it must be the last Thursday so the back-up command runs.

Comment: You will need to escape percent signs, like in the 2nd Saturday example.

Comment: If you have GNU date, it supports `-d "next thursday" +%m` so you can skip one nested subcommand.

Comment: @tripleee - I tested the command with `bash` on Ubuntu, and no escaping was necessary, though I didn't check it in `crontab`, because testing would be too difficult. I can imagine it would be necessary in a GNU/Windows environment, but I'll change my answer, as it can do no harm. Thanks for the "next Thursday" tip: it works on Ubuntu, so I'll incorporate it.

Comment: The escaping of percent signs is a requirement which is specific to `crontab` syntax; so yes, it would work at the prompt without escaping.

Comment: No time to test... waiting for the next Thursday. :)

Comment: @tripleee - OK, thanks. I've now found the discussion of percent signs in the manual page. I had erroneously assumed than the command would be passed verbatim to a shell. We live and learn.

Comment: @Danijel - I suggest you put in an extra, dummy command (eg to echo to a file) with the same time and test syntax, but specifying a time in the immediate future. This will make sure it _doesn't_ run unexpectedly. You'll have to wait until next Tuesday to make sure it _does_ run when expected. However, if you use the long form, having made sure it doesn't run today, change the seconds offset to `+604800*2` and it should then run. This will be a good check before next week comes round. Note my edit to escape the percent signs, after @tripleee's comments.

Comment: Oh and actually the `$((...))` stuff is a Bash extension, so is not strictly permitted in `crontab`, which runs `sh` always.  You can say `bash -c '...your script...'` or hope that `sh` is a `bash` which is not too strict about POSIX mode.

Comment: @tripleee - I did actually try it in `sh`, though on Ubuntu it is linked to `bash`, but it runs with `sh` syntax. It's also documented in the `sh` manual, though it is Korn- not Bourne-compatible. I did wonder about suggesting putting the test into a script which returns the result of the test: that could then be preceded by `#!/bin/bash`. Alternatively, it is possible to set the `SHELL` environment variable prior to launching `cron` so as to specify which shell to use.